# jQuery: How do I use `map` with classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some `div`s that share the same class `.job`.

```
<div class="job">
  <div id="title">Job 1</div>
  <div id="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div id="title">Job 2</div>
  <div id="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div id="title">Job 3</div>
  <div id="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div id="title">Job 3</div>
  <div id="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

From those divs, I want to create an array of the titles within those divs:

```
['Job 1', 'Job 2', 'Job 3']
```

I've tried:

```
$('.job').map(function(){ $('#title', this).text() })
> w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(4)]
```

and also:

```
$('.job').map(function(){ $('#title', this).text() }).toArray()
> []
```

and:

```
$('.job').toArray().map(function(){ $('#title', this).text() })
> [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

without success. What is the correct way to build the list I want? Why doesn't my first return the list of title strings?

Comment: You have duplicate `id` attributes all through that HTML sample, use `class` instead to group elements. You're also missing the `return` statement in the `map()` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return provided value in `.map()` using `return`.

```
$('.job').map(function(){ 
  return $('#title', this).text() 
}).toArray();
```

Or using **ES6** without `return`

```
$('.job').map((i, ele) => $('#title', ele).text()).toArray();
```

*Note that your html isn't valid because contain duplicate **`id`** attribute, so use **`class`** instead.*

```js
var arr = $('.job').map(function(){ 
  return $('.title', this).text() 
}).toArray();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 1</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 2</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 3</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 4</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

Also you can do this work using **pure javascript**

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".job .title")].map(v=>v.textContent);
```

```js
let arr = [...document.querySelectorAll(".job .title")].map(v=>v.textContent);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 1</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 2</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 3</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 4</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: and the OP should remove the duplicate IDs, too!

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, added

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change your duplicate ID attributes into classes - it's not legal HTML as written.

Having done that you can use this to obtain the text content which will be more efficient than invoking jQuery twice within the `.map` callback to first find the child node and then gets its content:

```
let arr = $('.job .title').get().map(el => el.textContent);
```

```js
let arr = $('.job .title').get().map(el => el.textContent);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 1</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 2</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 3</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="job">
  <div class="title">Job 3</div>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```